# Which soccer player played for the most national teams?

Tags: football

[Alfredo Di Stéfano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfredo_Di_St%C3%A9fano) back in the 50's-60's played for Argentina, Colombia, and Spain. Many soccer players played for 2 teams, but that's the only case I know of someone playing for 3 teams. Was he the player who played for the most national teams or was there another one?  Which soccer player played for the most national teams?

Comment: I saw the title and was going to suggest Di Stefano as an answer. I don't know of any other footballer who played for three different national teams, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. Just to complicate matters, [Di Stefano's appearances for Colombia aren't recognised by FIFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfredo_Di_St%C3%A9fano#Colombia), as the country wasn't a member of FIFA at the time.

Comment: Apparently he isnt the only one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Kilkenny

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia article, shouldn't the question say that he played for Spain (rather than Uruguay)?

Comment: @Martin I don't know how I didn't catch that, I've submitted an edit to fix it.

Comment: There is a Wikipedia article [List of nationality transfers in association football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nationality_transfers_in_association_football) - however, according to [the talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:List_of_nationality_transfers_in_association_football), there are several issues with that list.

Comment: @Martin I agree with you. The vast majority of the players on that list don't seem to have actually played for the team they were originally eligible for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Examples of player who played for three countries.

- As mentioned in the question, [Alfredo Di Stéfano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfredo_Di_St%C3%A9fano) played for Argentina and Spain. In addition to that, he played for Columbia - although those matches aren't in the official FIFA records.
- [László Kubala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_Kubala) played for Czechoslovakia, Hungary and Spain. Kubala also played for [Catalonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalonia_national_football_team) - however, this team is not a member of FIFA/UEFA.

If we also count caps at the youth level:

- [Daniel Brailovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Brailovsky) played for Uruguay at youth level and later represented Argentina and Israel.
- [Neil Kilkenny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Kilkenny) represented England and Ireland at the youth level, and later played for Australia.
- [Demitrius Omphroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demitrius_Omphroy) played for USA and Panama at youth level, as a senior for Phillippines.
- [Herolind Shala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herolind_Shala) played for Norway (youth level), Albania and Kosovo.
- [Alex Zahavi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Zahavi) played for Portugal, USA, Israel - in all three cases at the youth level.

**Sources:**

- Wikipedia article [FIFA eligibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_eligibility_rules) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=FIFA_eligibility_rules&oldid=929582937)).
- Wikipedia article [List of sportspeople who competed for more than one nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sportspeople_who_competed_for_more_than_one_nation#Men%E2%80%99s_Football_(soccer)) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_sportspeople_who_competed_for_more_than_one_nation&oldid=936309620#Men%E2%80%99s_Football_(soccer))).
- Wikipedia articles of individual players.
- [#FootballTrivia: These footballers played for more than one country](https://www.newsbytesapp.com/timeline/Sports/27289/122734/5-footballers-who-represented-more-than-one-country)

Comment: This answer was intentionally made [community wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) - feel free to edit it if you have some suitable additions.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [List of sportspeople who competed for more than one nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sportspeople_who_competed_for_more_than_one_nation#Men%E2%80%99s_Football_(soccer)) lists Sweden U21, Albania and Kosovo for Loret Sadiku, however the [article about the player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loret_Sadiku) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Loret_Sadiku&oldid=934306537) does not mention any caps for Albania.

Answer (score 1):

Di Stefano played for both Spain and Argentina and even Puskas played for Hungary and Spain.
Even Platini turned out  in a match for Kuwait.